# Write an array of type struct from query gorm in csv file

Tags: csv, go

I have a type struct like this:

```
type ExtParticipants struct {
  ParticipantId int `gorm:"PRIMARY_KEY"`
  ParticipantData time.Time
  EventId int
  UserId int
}
```

If, for example, i would obtain all participants in an event, i'll do the following query:

```
func GetParticipants(db *gorm.DB, eventId int) ([]*ExtParticipants, error) {
  var participants []*ExtParticipants
  query := db.Table("ext_participants").Where("event_id = ?", eventId).Find(&participants)
  return participants, query.Error
}
```

Is there a native method for writing to csv the output of that query (an array of structs ExtParticipants)?

From the library "encoding/csv" there is the following methods:

```
func (w *Writer) Write(record []string) error
func (w *Writer) WriteAll(records [][]string) error
```

That accept as input only an array or matrix of strings, but it would be ideal if there is an analogous method that accepts structs as input and will write as header the names of fields of the same struct.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv?

Comment: I'm trying it just now, thanks!